# Background-image scaling code breaking html placement

Tags: html, css, background-image, scale, scaling

I am using bootstrap and I want my background image to scale with the page, so this is the style code I used:

```css
html,
body {
  background: url(../imgs/ryze.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

And It seems to work, but it messes up my html placement which should be like this:
[Proper palcement(using template)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcBOT.png)

Instead the html bunches up at the top like this:
[What I get instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrQPI.jpg)*

***EDIT***
Here is the html that I used:

```html
<div class="site-wrapper">

      <div class="site-wrapper-inner">

        <div class="cover-container">

          <div class="masthead clearfix">
            <div class="inner">
              <h3 class="masthead-brand">Cover</h3>
              <nav>
                <ul class="nav masthead-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#about">Who Are We</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#contact">News and Events</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Products<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Ryze Vodka</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Inferno Whiskey</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Bourbon on Oak</a></li>
                      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Seasonal</li>
                      <li><a href="#">Liquid Candycane</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Locktenders' Gin</a></li>

                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                  <li> <a href="#">Where to Buy? </a></li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="inner cover" id="ryze">
            <h1 class="cover-heading">Ryze Vodka</h1>
            <p class="lead">Our Ryze Vodka is made from locally grown winter wheat and rye, and is distilled three times through volcanic ash and active carbon for a smooth and clean finish</p>

          </div>

          <div class="mastfoot">
            <div class="inner">
              <p>Cover template for <a href="http://getbootstrap.com">Bootstrap</a>, by <a href="https://twitter.com/mdo">@mdo</a>.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
```

This is the html that gets buched up at the top, and all classes are from bootsrap template. Hope this helps

Comment: this looks like a DOM issue, can you provide us the HTML structure of this section? It will help us see if you have any bootstrap classes or structure issues that we can identify

Comment: You are setting two background images here, one on the html and one on the body element. Other than that, there's not much this can change about placements of other elements on the page. Are you sure this causes the problem? I.E. does the problem go away if you comment this out?

Comment: @Mr Lister I realized what I did, I deleted part of the base css for the template, a "height:100%;" in the body, now it is fixed thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to fix that. Pull the page up and open Developer Tools console (press cnrtl + shift + i). Highlight the misbehaving element and Chrome will show you it's placement + padding + margin.

You can modify the CSS in the dev tools to see changes / fixes in real time. Hope this helps.

[image]